# Javadoc in Eclipse failing to recognize packages

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

Thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818204/how-to-generate-links-to-the-android-classes-reference-in-javadoc), I was able to get Javadoc links to work for my Android project within Eclipse on Windows.  Specifically, "{@link android.widget.Toast}" is currently converted into a link to "http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html?is-external=true".  I achieved this with the Javadoc option:

> -linkoffline http://d.android.com/reference
>   "file:/C:/Android/android-sdk-windows/docs/reference"

However, I get errors such as the following based on lines of my Java code (not the Javadoc comments):

```
C:\Users\Ellen\workspace\TestableToast\src\edu\mills\cs180\HelloAndroid.java:5: 
package android.view does not exist
import android.view.View;
                   ^ 
C:\Users\Ellen\workspace\TestableToast\src\edu\mills\cs180\HelloAndroid.java:6: 
package android.view.View does not exist 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
                        ^ 
C:\Users\Ellen\workspace\TestableToast\src\edu\mills\cs180\HelloAndroid.java:8: 
package android.widget does not exist
import android.widget.Toast;
                      ^ 
C:\Users\Ellen\workspace\TestableToast\src\edu\mills\cs180\HelloAndroid.java:10: 
cannot find symbol symbol: class Activity 
public class HelloAndroid extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
                                  ^
```

How can I fix these references?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This Works in Eclipse for me:

1. Project --> generate Javadoc
2. Go to "Configure Javadoc arguments."
3. in VM options add "-bootclasspath /path/to/sdk/platforms/android-##/android.jar"

Comment: Its works without quotes for me. quotes generate unrecognized tag error.

Comment: This also works for Android Studio by the way. I just flawlessly generated a JavaDoc for my Android library project using **-bootclasspath /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar**

Comment: This solution works for one developer, but not for a whole team. Isn't there a solution without a hardcoded local path? Something I could add to the gradle build task to publicize the classpath dynamically?

Answer (score 40):

Adding `-classpath` parameter in the last screen of "Generate Javadoc..." wizard did not work for me: I got an error message saying that `-classpath` parameter can only be specified once.

Not really a solution, but a workaround:

- In the "Generate Javadoc..." wizard, check the option "Save the settings of this Javadoc export as an Ant script". This generates `javadoc.xml` file in project directory
- Edit `javadoc.xml` file and edit classpath attribute. Specifically, add "/path/to/sdk/platforms/android-##/android.jar" there and any other jars that you get warning messages about
- Generate the javadoc with: `ant -buildfile javadoc.xml`. For convenience, I put this line in a `javadoc.sh` shell script.

Comment: Thank you! I was finally able to generate my Javadoc. It might be worth adding that you can execute the buildfile from the Eclipse Ant View (adding the builfile and then run it). I had to do it that way as javadoc refused the -buildfile parameter.

Comment: I got the same error -- however, if you change the `-classpath` to `-bootclasspath` then it works fine.

Answer (score 7):

You need to put the android classes in your javadoc classpath, too. For this, add the android jar file to the `-classpath` argument of javadoc (as you would do for your compiler).

I have no idea whether and where Eclipse gives you some configuration option for this, though.

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.  The last screen in the "Generate Javadoc..." wizard allows the specification of command-line options, so I added '-classpath "C:/Android/android-sdk-windows/platforms/android-4/android.jar"'.

Comment: I receive a "javadoc: error - The -classpath option may be specified no more than once., error now."

Comment: @KarlMorrison if your command line already has a `-classpath ...` option, you should not add another one, but add the jar file to the existing one (separated by `;` on windows and `:` on unix systems).

Answer (score 7):

Project > generate Javadoc. Then, go to "Configure Javadoc arguments" and
in VM options add "-bootclasspath /path/to/sdk/platforms/android-##/android.jar".

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to answer provided by @PaŭloEbermann and @MarcelD-B, I was able to understand the root cause of the issue. However, since I am using `Android Studio`, I was bit confused as to where to add the `argument.` After some time, I was able to figure it out finally and I am putting it as an answer here for any other person who finds the similar issue.

For `Android Studio`, open `Tools > Generate JavaDocs` and  add the following `argument` in `Other command line arguments:`-

```
-bootclasspath /path/to/sdk/platforms/android-##/android.jar
```

**Note:-** There's no need of adding any commas in the `argument.` However, if your `SDK Path` contains spaces then enclose the path in double quotes (`"`). eg- My `SDK Path` contains spaces so I used the `argument`-

```
-bootclasspath "F:\Android SDK\platforms\android-21\android.jar"
```

[image: JavaDoc generation screen on Android Studio]

Answer (score 3):

the answers above are quite good! include the classpath in your javadoc.xml and run is via ant-command or eclipse -> Run As -> Ant Build

BUT be sure that there are no whitespaces in the paths! I had this problems with C:/Program Files/... and it didn't work till i changed it to C:/Progra~1/...

also putting the path in quotes didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Eclipse solution**

Adding the `android.jar` to -classpath is indeed the correct approach. No ANT is necessary, though also viable. In case you want to be using Eclipse GUI (File->Export->Java->Javadoc) for generating Javadoc, there's no option to edit classpath in the dialog. You need to have the classpath set correctly beforehand. Two ways to achieve that:

1. Edit manually the `<path_to_your_project>/.classpath` and add the following line:

   ```
   <classpathentry kind="lib" path="<path_to_your_android_skd>/platforms/android-<version>/android.jar"/>
   ```
2. Right click on your project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External JARs->navigate to `<path_to_your_android_skd>/platforms/android-<version>/android.jar`

I found the Eclipse GUI approach better than using ANT hinted in some of the answers here because you get clickable references to your source code on any Javadoc warning/error in Console. When using ANT all you get in Console is printed output of the javadoc.exe command.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround in eclipse worked for me:

1. Go to Project=>Properties and select "Java Build Path"
2. Select "Order and Export" tab
3. Move  "android 2.x.x"  and "Android Dependencies"  to  the top of the list