# Eclipse Android generate javadoc warning

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

I am trying to generate the javadoc for my Android app in Eclipse. I've done the following steps:

File -> Export -> Java -> Javadoc -> Check project and enter destination, press finish

This generates many warnings/errors regarding 'cannot find symbol ...' which is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157433/javadoc-for-android-project-in-eclipse-fails-with-nullpointerexception)

Following the solution from that post, I export as an ant script which creates javadoc.xml
I then added the path to my android.jar to the classpath field.

If I run the script I get one warning which reads:

> warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
>        javadoc:
>
> error - Illegal package name: ""

The console also says Loading source files for package ...., for each package and then build successful. 
But the only thing generated is an empty directory doc.

After searching for a solution to this I found an [article](http://www.joshuajacobs.name/2009/05/05/intellij-javadoc-error-javadoc-error-illegal-package-name/) which says the problem comes from having spaces in the class path names. I check my paths and sure enough I have a space in 'Program Files'. I've tried to fixing this by delimiting the space several ways but I can't get it to work. Just to see what happens I deleted the offending line from the class path and the same error occurs..so that leads me to believe the error may lay elsewhere. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I found a discussion [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6370402) that pointed me to checking my CLASSPATH environment variable. I had a duplicate value.. '.;' and '%CLASSPATH%.;' I removed the latter and the error went away.

I'm still left with the warning noted above, "bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5". It's not causing any problems that I can notice, but if anyone knows a way to fix it that would be great