# How to generate Javadoc with ADT r17

Tags: android, javadoc, adt

It seems that many problems arise when people updated the ADT and SDK to the newest revision r17.
I have a problem generating the Javadoc for my Android JAR project that uses Android Bluetooth library.
Using revision r16, the trick below works :

```
-classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-13/android.jar"
-linkoffline http://d.android.com/reference "file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/docs/reference"
```

But after I updated to r17, It happens again. I deleted the classpath line, because it is already included in r17, but I still got:

```
error: package android.bluetooth does not exist

    and

error: cannot find symbol ....
```

It seems that no one has asked this question. Anybody can help?
Thank you.

Comment: For more information gp through this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200234/javadoc-in-eclipse-failing-to-recognize-packages)!

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that you have given the proper Android Javadoc location to Android.jar file...

If not then do the following:-

Right click on Project >> Properties >> JavaBuildPath >> Select Libraries Tab >> Android X.X >> Javadoc location >> Browse Javadoc location from android installation folder (i.e file:/C:/#Android Installed Directory/sdk/docs/reference/)

Now add the following line in the VM Options Textfield (i.e in the last page)
-bootclasspath C:/#Android Installed Directory/sdk/platforms/android-X.X/android.jar

Hope this post is helpful to you :-)

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. In an ADT Project, the android.jar is not listed unded 'Referenced Libraried' so I think, that's why the Javadoc-Tool missed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the android.jar(from android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-10/android.jar) in libs folder .

This can solve this question , but I know it is not the best.