# Eclipse: Javadoc generation creating empty doc directory

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have documented my code and will now want to generate Javadoc in a doc directory in my root directory of my project.

Problem? Whenever I try to generate, all the shows up is an empty directory in the root directory.

This is the error: **FIRST ERROR FIXED! Had to add JRE to my eniromental variables.**

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
```

**Now this is the problem:**

```
Loading source files for package com.example.worldfriends...
Loading source files for package com.example.json...
Loading source files for package com.google.android.gms...
Loading source files for package com.example.util...
Constructing Javadoc information...
C:\Programming\workspace\worldfriends\src\com\example\worldfriends\CustomMapFragment.java:8: error: package android.graphics does not exist
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
                   ^
C:\Programming\workspace\worldfriends\src\com\example\worldfriends\CustomMapFragment.java:9: error: package android.graphics.drawable does not exist
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
                                ^
C:\Programming\workspace\worldfriends\src\com\example\worldfriends\CustomMapFragment.java:10: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Bundle;
                 ^
C:\Programming\workspace\worldfriends\src\com\example\worldfriends\CustomMapFragment.java:11: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

C:\Programming\workspace\worldfriends\src\com\example\worldfriends\CustomMapFragment.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflator, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
                             ^
  symbol:   class LayoutInflater
  location: class CustomMapFragment
```

Theres a few more lines after that.

After trying to add the following Configure Javadoc arguments:

```
-classpath "C:\Programming\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar"
```

I get this error:

```
javadoc: error - The -classpath option may be specified no more than once.
```

After loking around on Stackoverflow found this thread: [Javadoc in Eclipse failing to recognize packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200234/javadoc-in-eclipse-failing-to-recognize-packages?rq=1)

**ANSWER:**

```
This Works in Eclipse for me:

Projekt --> generate Javadoc
Go to "Configure Javadoc arguments."
in VM options add "-bootclasspath /path/to/sdk/platforms/android-##/android.jar"
```

Comment: Howare you generating the Javadoc?

Comment: Via Project/Generate Javadoc. I've updated with more errors.

Comment: VM option did the trick. Thanks