# Android import issue

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to fix 2 errors in my android project and they both seem related to the same issue. Right now my error log is telling me the following:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for android.os.Bundle. Fix the build path then try
>   building this project

Likewise the second error states:

> The type android.os.Bundle cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

However, I have tried googling for a fix to this but found nothing. I have tried to re-import my os bundle, but nothing happens.

Has anyone ever came across this error before, and if so, how did you get rid of it?

Comment: Which version of ADT are you using?

Comment: No idea, how do I find that out?

Comment: Goto eclipse click Help>About

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5450375/1318946

Comment: @insomniac ADT version 22.3.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200234/javadoc-in-eclipse-failing-to-recognize-packages/8182949#8182949