# Android Eclipse: javadoc errors while generating javadoc

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javadoc

I have no experience in using javadoc utility. I am trying to create java docs for a class from ADT eclipse. I have downloaded the docs and specifying the javadoc URL for android.jar to the downloaded docs. It seems like it is not able to get docs for the android apis

This is the error i am getting.

```
Loading source file C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java...
Constructing Javadoc information...
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:6: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Context;
                      ^
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:7: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Intent;
                      ^
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:8: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Bundle;
                 ^
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:9: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Parcelable;
                 ^
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:10: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                   ^
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:11: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.Menu;
                   ^
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:12: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.MenuItem;
                   ^
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:13: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.View;
                   ^
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:23: error: cannot access ViewGroup
public class AppTutorial extends ActionBarActivity {
       ^
  class file for android.view.ViewGroup not found
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class Bundle
  location: class AppTutorial
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                                       ^
  symbol:   class Menu
  location: class AppTutorial
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                                             ^
  symbol:   class MenuItem
  location: class AppTutorial
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:66: error: cannot access Activity
    class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    ^
  class file for android.app.Activity not found
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
                                      ^
  symbol:   class View
  location: class AppTutorial.CustomPagerAdapter
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
                                ^
  symbol:   class View
  location: class AppTutorial.CustomPagerAdapter
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class View
  location: class AppTutorial.CustomPagerAdapter
C:\Users\Abhishek\Documents\GitHub\Mobile-applications\Learn from Map\App\LearnFromMap\src\org\buildmlearn\learnfrommap\AppTutorial.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
        public Parcelable saveState() {
               ^
  symbol:   class Parcelable
  location: class AppTutorial.CustomPagerAdapter
javadoc: warning - Error fetching URL: file:/E:/GSoC/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321/sdk/docs/package-list
Standard Doclet version 1.7.0_45
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:83)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:44)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl.superclassType(ClassDocImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:459)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:497)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.processType(ClassTree.java:194)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.buildTree(ClassTree.java:146)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.<init>(ClassTree.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:123)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:83)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
18 warnings
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer here :

[Javadoc in Eclipse failing to recognize packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200234/javadoc-in-eclipse-failing-to-recognize-packages)

Adding *-bootclasspath* option in VM options solves the problem.