# Android Studio fails to read packages while generating JavaDoc

Tags: java, android

I've seen questions with Eclipse Javadoc so far [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351245/android-eclipse-javadoc-errors-while-generating-javadoc), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200234/javadoc-in-eclipse-failing-to-recognize-packages/8182949#8182949) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157433/javadoc-for-android-project-in-eclipse-fails-with-nullpointerexception) but these are specific to Eclipse. But I want it for ANDROID STUDIO. My project has submodules and customview. Below is the error:

```
BootStarp1\Base-App\src\main\java\com\rspllib\android\utils\FileUpload\CustomMultiPartEntity.java:3: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.Log;
                   ^
D:\MonkeyTalk\MonkeyStudioWorkspace\BootStarp1\Base-App\src\main\java\com\rspllib\android\utils\FileUpload\CustomMultiPartEntity.java:18: error: cannot access HttpEntity
public class CustomMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity
       ^
         class file for org.apache.http.HttpEntity not found
         D:\MonkeyTalk\MonkeyStudioWorkspace\BootStarp1\Base-            App\src\main\java\com\rspllib\android\utils\FileUpload\FileUploading.java:3: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.Log;
                   ^
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63249) I could finally apply the workaround. Make sure you give the path till your android-jar in the "Other command line arguments" field viz:

```
    -bootclasspath D:\android-studio-.3.2\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar
```

do not forget to add "-bootclasspath".[image]

Comment: "error: option --boot-class-path not allowed with target 11"