# error: package android.app does not exist

Tags: android, javadoc

i tried to generate Javadoc in Android Studio (Not in Eclipse) and got many errors like:

```
D:\android studio\[...].java:3: error: package android.app does not exist
import android.app.Activity;
```

The file for which i try to generate it is inside a module and no, it doesn't have `apply plugin 'com.android.application'` in the build.gradle, but `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and the version numbers are all the same.
The project can be build and runs

Comment: Post your build.gradle file.

Comment: nvm, found the solution here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520220/android-studio-fails-to-read-packages-while-generating-javadoc