# Error in using generate javadoc for android project in eclipse

Tags: android, javadoc

I have tried many solution available but unable to create javadoc for my android project.
checked out the following:
[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101867/generate-a-javadoc-for-my-android-project)
[solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818204/how-to-generate-links-to-the-android-classes-reference-in-javadoc)

but i got the following error
Building tree for all the packages and classes...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:83)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:44)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl.superclassType(ClassDocImpl.java:496).....
```

Also tried ant command tool
ant -f javadoc.xml

But no output
on console last output is null pointer exception and "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" but no files generated in dest folder...

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution

adding the following lines to the javadoc.xml worked for me

```
classpath="D:\AndroidEclipse\android-sdks\platforms\android-8\android.jar;libs/GraphView-3.0.jar.....
```

I just added path of the android.jar file and executed the ant -f javadoc.xml command and my documentation has been created

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create java doc from eclipse, add android.jar in lib folder of your project. And then go to Project .. Generate javadoc. 
This worked for me.